# How can I make effects plots for a lmer mixed model?

Tags: r, lme4

I've used the `effects` package for `lm` and `glm` models successfully before.  It's supposed to support `lme4` mixed models, but I can't get it to work for most cases.

Any advice?  I have a reproducible example below with two valid `lmer` models that produce `effects` errors.

Are there any alternative packages for calculating and plotting model effects?

```r
library(lme4)
library(effects)

# example from documentation works
fm1 <- lmer(angle ~ recipe * temperature + (1|recipe:replicate), cake,
            REML = FALSE)
print(Effect(c("recipe", "temperature"), fm1))
#> 
#>  recipe*temperature effect
#>       temperature
#> recipe      175      185      195      205      215      225
#>      A 29.13333 31.53333 30.80000 33.53333 38.66667 35.06667
#>      B 26.86667 29.40000 31.73333 32.13333 34.46667 35.26667
#>      C 27.93333 28.93333 31.73333 30.86667 34.40000 35.73333

# this is a valid model with no singularities 
fm2 <- lmer(angle ~ temp + (1 | replicate), cake)
print(fm2)
#> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#> Formula: angle ~ temp + (1 | replicate)
#>    Data: cake
#> REML criterion at convergence: 1671.711
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups    Name        Std.Dev.
#>  replicate (Intercept) 6.260   
#>  Residual              4.849   
#> Number of obs: 270, groups:  replicate, 15
#> Fixed Effects:
#> (Intercept)         temp  
#>      0.5159       0.1580

# effects doesn't work
Effect(c("temp", "replicate"), fm2)
#> Error in Analyze.model(focal.predictors, mod, xlevels, default.levels, : the following predictor is not in the model: replicate
Effect(c("replicate"), fm2)
#> Error in Analyze.model(focal.predictors, mod, xlevels, default.levels, : the following predictor is not in the model: replicate
Effect(c("temp"), fm2)
#> 
#>  temp effect
#> temp
#>      180      190      200      210      220 
#> 28.96159 30.54190 32.12222 33.70254 35.28286

# this doesn't work either
my_cake <- cake
my_cake <- within(my_cake, temp <- temp - mean(temp))
fm3 <- lmer(angle ~ (temp || replicate), my_cake)

Effect(c("temp", "replicate"), fm3)
#> Error in Analyze.model(focal.predictors, mod, xlevels, default.levels, : the following predictors are not in the model: temp, replicate
Effect(c("replicate"), fm3)
#> Error in Analyze.model(focal.predictors, mod, xlevels, default.levels, : the following predictor is not in the model: replicate
Effect(c("temp"), fm3)
#> Error in Analyze.model(focal.predictors, mod, xlevels, default.levels, : the following predictor is not in the model: temp
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Would the `emmeans` package help? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html#plot.emmGrid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to plot effects involving random terms. In your first example, your effects only involve fixed-effect terms.

The closest I can get quickly is

```r
cowplot::plot_grid(
   plot(Effect("temp", fm2)),
   lattice::dotplot(ranef(fm2))$replicate
)
```

[image: effects plot]

or

```r
library(sjPlot)
cowplot::plot_grid(
   plot_model(fm2, "eff")$temp,
   plot_model(fm2, "re")
)
```

[image: effects plot 2]

- I don't think that either `emmeans` or `effects` handle random effects
- the `sjPlot` package has a lot of different capabilities, but I don't think treating random effects as 'effects' is one of them
- note that the replicate effects shown here are values relative to the overall mean, not predicted values

As shown [here](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_randomeffects.html), you can generate a prediction plot with up to 9 randomly sampled levels, but it's not (AFAICT) possible to use >9 levels (because of a hard-coded restriction on the number of colours!)

```r
plot(ggpredict(fm2, terms = c("temp", "replicate [sample = 9]"), type ="random"))
```